# PHP print nested array foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which I want to make readable for users:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [price] => 4.00
            [per] => day
            [count] => 
            [type] => single
            [status] => T
            [extra_quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [price] => 12.00
            [per] => day
            [count] => 
            [type] => single
            [status] => T
            [extra_quantity] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to echo this to show users the following readable line for every subarray:

`[id] = [price] per [day]`

I am fairly new to arrays, especially nested one like the one I have above, how should I go with this to get an output like I need? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, try: foreach($array as $item) { echo $item['id'] . ' = ' . $item['price'] . ' per ' . $item['per']; }

Comment: what you have is a multi-dimensional array. Do a foreach and reference the key

Answer (score 2):

use  `foreach()` built in function which help you get all data as readable

```
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo $row['price'].'per'.$row['per'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

check for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, works perfectly. I learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

FOreach loops are used when iterating over arrays.The above is a multi-dimensional array. Meaning An array in an array

```
  foreach($array as $value):
    if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $value) && array_key_exists($value['price'], $value) && array_key_exists($value['per'], $value)):
     #we have the keys present.
     echo $value['price'].'per'.$value['per'];
    endif;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, works perfectly. I learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Awesome! My pleasure!